# use index instead of name to access class member variables

Tags: c++, database, templates

Say I have a class :

```
struct CAT
{
    //In order to simplify the problem, supposing the possible 
    // types of member variables are just int,double or string
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;
    int d;
    ....
};
```

In my case,I have to write a function so that each member variable can be access using its index.

for example:

```
CAT cat;
setValue(cat,0,10);
setValue(cat,1,2.1);
setValue(cat,2,"hello");
setValue(cat,3,123);
//or
int i=1;
setValue(cat,i,2.1)
```

the first idea come to my mind is to use template:

```
    template<typename T>
    void setValue(CAT &c, int idx, T value)
    {
          if (0 == idx){
              c.a = value;   //compile failure when using setValue(c,2,"hello")
          } else if( 1 == idx){  
              c.b = value;  
          } else if( 2 == idx){  
              c.b = value;   //compile failure when using setValue(c,0,10)
          }
          ...
    }
```

But it will not work because of the comments inside the codes.

Any ideas for it?

Thanks in advance.

**MODIFIED:**

I need to write a program to convert multiple tables and their records into different c structs ,for example:
table CAT, its schema is:

```
CAT(a,b,c,d,....)
```

convert to

```
struct S_CAT  //this is generate automatically by code
{
    int a;
    double b;
    string c;
    int d;
    ...
};

//automatically generate some code to write all records of table CAT to struct S_CAT
```

it is easy to generate the code for create the c struct automatically, but it is hard to generate codes to put records into it.

Comment: What do you need this for? There’s probably a better solution.

Comment: Does the index need to be dynamic (i.e. known only during execution)? If so, there is no solution that would maintain type safety.

Comment: @LucTouraille, the indexes are dynamic, actually they are the indexes of table columns ,so they will changed according to different table.

Comment: And this shows why the database world needs to catch up with the programming world. SQL is about as typesafe as C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I have made some changes on the post to explain why I need to do that

Comment: Do you have a database system in mind?  Some database systems have nonstandard ways to map structs and tables.

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular method overloading, or provide several specializations of the template:

```
void setValue(CAT &c, int idx, int value) {
    if (0 == idx) {
        c.a = value;
    } else if (3 == idx) {
        c.d = value;
    } else {
        Assert(false, "wrong type for index");
    }
}
void setValue(CAT &c, int idx, double value) {
    if (1 == idx) {
        c.b = value;
    } else {
        Assert(false, "wrong type for index");
    }
}
void setValue(CAT &c, int idx, string value) {
    if (2 == idx) {
        c.c = value;
    } else {
        Assert(false, "wrong type for index");
    }
}
```